# Работа tutorial vuex без Webpack

Tags: vue.js

Есть документация по Vuex, и буквально сразу же идет туториал по созданию простейшего приложения с Vuex: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/tutorial.html

Тут набросал, ровно тот туториал (в index.html пытался завести его): https://github.com/stranger-ru/vue-tutorial

Вроде все просто, но не могу понять, как можно его сделать (завести) без Webpack, и можно ли вообще сделать (завести) его без Webpack, подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы собираетесь использовать однофайловые компоненты, то необходим `Webpack` для компиляции этих файлов в "нативный" **JavaScript** код.
Если вы хотите использовать `Vue` без `WebPack` то необходимо в разметке **HTML** страницы подключить библиотеку `Vue` через `<script>`, и затем описывать компоненты  Vue исопользуя нативнй **JavaScript** код на странице (или в отдельном файле, подключив его в странницу), типа:

```
    Vue.component('component',{
      template: '<h1>Это компонент</h1>'
      .....
});

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app'
      .....
});
```